# Downloading Images through Wget With Proxy

Tags: bash, proxy, wget, ruby

I've written a ruby tool to download multiple images. However, this time I'm having to configure wget with a proxy. `Prefix` is the specified directory of where I want the images to go and `md5_sum` is a method that hex digests the given uri and `proxy` is the configured proxy the user specifies to the bot. What have I done wrong?

**Command:**

`` `wget -q -O #{prefix}/#{md5_sum(uri)} \
    -e use_proxy=yes -e https_proxy=#{proxy}` ``

Comment: `${prefix}`, `${proxy}` and maybe `$(md5_sum($uri))`

Comment: I also forgot the ```secondary -e``` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake, but for anyone who might need help I'll add an answer. I hope this will. When trying to configure a proxy on the spot, you must specify -e for both options.

`` `wget -q -O #{prefix}/#{md5_sum(uri)} \
    -e use_proxy=yes -e https_proxy=#{proxy}` ``

Comment: `${prefix}`, `${proxy}` and maybe `$(md5_sum($uri))`